# How to read a cookie in the browser with Dart?

Tags: browser, dart

Question looks simple but I couldn't find in the docs how to read a cookie with Dart on client side without 3-rd party libs.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `dart:html` library you can use [`document.cookie`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-html/Document/cookie.html). This will return a `String` of *all* the cookies on the client. Each cookie is separated with a semi-colon and the key value pairs are separated with a `"="`. Example;

```
"foo=bar; otherFoo=otherBar"
```

So it's up to you to split the `String` accordingly into a data type that you want to work with.

Also see: [Document.cookie - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 4):

I use [document.cookie](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.22.0/dart-html/Document/cookie.html) and this class to maintain the cookies.

```
import 'dart:html';

class CookieManager {

  static addToCookie(String key, String value) {
    document.cookie = "$key=$value;";
  }
  
  static String getCookie(String key) {

    String cookies = document.cookie;
    List<String> listValues = cookies.isNotEmpty ? cookies.split(";") : List();
    String matchVal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < listValues.length; i++) {
      List<String> map = listValues[i].split("=");
      String _key = map[0].trim();
      String _val = map[1].trim();
      if (key == _key) {
        matchVal = _val;
        break;
      }
    }
    return matchVal;
  }
}
```