# How to save data in browser's cookies using Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In my Flutter Web Application I want to save some of my app-s data in user's browser cookies. Such as Layout condition, that are changing by user. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565211/how-to-read-a-cookie-in-the-browser-with-dart) solve your question. If not, please post what is not working along with some amount code or research you already carried out. You may also try to see if `shared_preferences` package solves your requirement as it already supports flutter web as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need cookies to store app data? You may want to consider looking into using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). If you're just storing simple data, these can be simply mapped to SharedPreferences, and the package has support for web and mobile.